# On working principal of the low DC voltage charger of this certain behavior

Tags: charger, voltage-measurement

How is the simple working mechanism or principal of the DC stage of a typically low DC voltage, ~ 5V, charger with the behavior:

- if a MM simply testing its  voltage it gives 0 volt
- if a battery is set in at its place on the charger and MM testing, reading it, it's giving the voltage of the battery plus a little bit more

Just wondering its circuit method for some days to no avail, please help sincerely

Comment: Please write a specific question

Comment: And provide any relevant details.  Which charger? Which battery chemistry? Can you link to the datasheet or provide a part number? Do you have a schematic or even a photo of the device?  It probably runs a battery detect routine, so if there is no battery it doesn't output any voltage.  Then when charging it sources a current into the battery and may eventually go to a constant voltage, so the voltage reads slightly higher than the battery voltage.  Depending on the chemistry it may end up with a float voltage after charging or it may terminate the charge.